# Bash substituting environment variable in command

Tags: bash, appveyor

I am trying to authenticate with GitHub using a password defined in an environment variable in AppVeyor.

The command that I am trying to execute is:

```
git remote add origin https://username:$EnvPassword@github.com/username/Empty.git
```

In the above scenario, I want `$EnvPassword` to be substituted with the password defined in my environment variable.

I thought prefixing with a `$` would be enough, but it isn't working at all. I can't seem to find anything about it anywhere else online.

Comment: If you put `echo` in front of the command, what does it say? (Well, don't show us the password.)

Comment: First things first: does it work if you put your password explicitly in the URL rather than using the parameter expansion?

Comment: For complex commands consider the stronger syntax `${EnvPassword}` instead of `$EnvPassword`

Comment: this works if you set the variable in bash. i suspect that whatever you set in appveyor is not a bash environment variable or needs to be accessed with a certain prefix or something, but i don't know appveyor.

Comment: please provide more detail about where and how you configure the environment variable and the script.

Comment: @brunorey your suggestion worked.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `$EnvPassword` with the more robust version `${EnvPassword}`. This type of substitution is usually better for complex commands.

```
git remote add origin https://username:${EnvPassword}@github.com/username/Empty.git
```